# Transparent buttons in UIMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm actually having the opposite problem of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333855/change-navigation-button-color-in-mfmailcomposerviewcontroller-on-ios-7) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736481/how-do-i-make-the-color-of-uibarbuttonitems-for-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-from) StackOverflow question. The 'Cancel' and 'Send' buttons on my instance of MFMailComposeViewController are both transparent. I've attached screenshots to show this.

[image: Cancel Button]

[image: Send Button]

When I set up the instance of the MFMailComposeViewController, I don't have any code changing the color from the system default. How do I make sure that these buttons are the system default color?

Comment: Are you by any chance setting appearance options somewhere in your app?

Comment: Hi @Krumelur, as far as I can tell, just with the method below appears in the project (I've inherited it, so I'm not yet completely sure how the appearance has been set). 

- (void)updateStatusBarAppearance
{
    if (IsIOS7()) [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Krumelur suggested, the appearance options were being set somewhere else in my app. The solution to override these options was to insert the following line in the method where the instance of MFMailComposeViewController was initialized:

```
mailComposer.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```